# How to fetch Array of String Data iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following type of data and i stuck in how to fetch that data.

```
  "(\n        {\n        RecordID = \"<CPRecord: 0x188471b0 ABPerson>\";\n        birthday = \"\";\n        emailAddress = \"\";\n        firstName = Communication;\n        imageData = \"\";\n        jobTitle = \"\";\n        lastName = A;\n        note = \"\";\n        organizationName = \"\";\n        phoneIdentifier = \"91E0D30B-EDB9-4735-BE46-A000F6D10A15\";\n        phoneNumber = \"\";\n        userName = \"Communication A\";\n    },\n        {\n        RecordID = \"<CPRecord: 0x18847340 ABPerson>\";\n        birthday = \"\";\n        emailAddress = \"\";\n        firstName = Communication;\n        imageData = \"\";\n        jobTitle = \"\";\n        lastName = A;\n        note = \"\";\n        organizationName = \"\";\n)"
```

Comment: Data format is not understandable. Please give a clear quote.

Comment: @Amanpreet i have fetched that data from sqlite database

Comment: from where you get this data ? and in which type ? string or NSData ?

Comment: @Inder is your issue resolved??

Comment: @SurajSukale not working

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone messed up in a major way when they stored the data into your SQL database. This looks like what the description property would return for a dictionary, and that's absolute rubbish to put into a database.

You will absolutely not be able to sort this out reliably. Talk to whoever is responsible for storing the data and make them clean up their mess. Or have a bit of fun with them and ask them for a format spec (not that anything useful will be forthcoming).

One reason why you will not be able to sort this out is because the genius writing to the database wrote the memory addresses of CPRecords (whatever CPRecords are). Someone created this garbage data, let them sort it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what do you want exactly,but i think you want like-->

**Update 2**

in your `.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *your_array;
```

in your `.m` file

```
NSString *str = [NSString StringwithFormat:@"%@",yourstring];
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
your_array=[NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

**Update 1**

Store your data in array, like `your_array`.

then do like following way:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *content = [self.your_array objectAtIndex:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"//your_cell_identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.Title setText:[content valueForKey:@"RecordID"]];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: @ Suraj Sukale this is the error
 [<__NSCFString 0x68b7000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key RecordID.

Comment: @Inder are you try to display it anywhere??means are you try to display RecordID in textfield,label,etc?

Comment: display on tableView Cell label

Comment: my array is not in the array formate, its in the string formate that why i can't getting the proper result.
Check the above formate

Comment: can i share my screen with teamviewer. you just check the code

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not using teamviewer..@Inder

Comment: you say, what is exact issue now you are facing, we will solve it.

Comment: actually i fetched the data from sqlite and the data formate is
(
        {
        firstName = Communication;
        lastName = A;
        userName = "Communication A";
    },
        {
        firstName = Communication;
        lastName = A;
        userName = "Communication A";
    })

Comment: Actually this is not the array its string

Comment: if i print  then 
NSLog(@"%@",[array valueForKey:@" firstName"]);

output :
 reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x69aa000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key firstName.'

Comment: @Inder first you need to take dict from array, after that `firstName`.

Comment: (
    "(\n        {\n        RecordID = \"<CPRecord: 0x167162a0 ABPerson>\";\n        birthday = \"\";\n        emailAddress = \"\";\n        firstName = Communication;\n        imageData = \"\";\n        jobTitle = \"\";\n        lastName = A;\n        note = \"\";\n        organizationName = \"\";\n        phoneIdentifier = \"91E0D30B-EDB9-4735-BE46-A000F6D10A15\";\n        phoneNumber = \"\";\n        userName = \"Communication A\";\n    }")

Comment: This is the string that i got

Comment: are you doing like above answer? if yes, then what you got when you print NSLog(@"%@", your_array);

Comment: i got string mention in the last comment when i print your_array